# get ID in json through find(:all)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a little User table in my database which I want to get in javascript.

So i've set up a jquery get function which gets the user.json properly. I get all the data from the users except for the ID. Is there any way I can get the ID along with the rest of the user's data?

user.controller.rb

```
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.find(:all)
  end
```

Javascript:

```
function getUsers() {
    $.get('http://localhost:3000/users.json?callback=?', function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
}
```

Comment: if i use `Model.find(:all)` I get the id back.. Can we see your Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's jbuilder --- by default it doesn't include the IDs, it includes the URL to get more information about the model.

**app/views/users/show.json.jbuilder**

```
json.extract! @user, :name, :created_at, :updated_at
```

Instead, add in the id to show:

```
json.extract! @user, :id, :name, :created_at, :updated_at
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot when I'm behind my laptop again. I'll follow up :)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon)? Give it a try, it might help you.